# How to use LEA with brackets?

Tags: visual-c++, pointers, assembly, x86

I have this ASM function, that takes 4 arguments. The first two arguments are passed by value, the last two are passed by reference. So I'm using this:

```
PUSH EBP
MOV EBP, ESP
SUB ESP, 20
MOV EAX, [EBP+8]
MOV EBX, [EBP+12]
LEA ECX, [EBP+16]
LEA EDX, [EBP+20]
PUSH EDX
PUSH ECX
PUSH EBX
PUSH EAX
CALL Function
LEAVE
RETN 20
```

(Note that I'm using this code inside C++ using the VC's `__asm` statement).

But while searching about the use of `LEA` to pass arguments as pointers (aka by reference) I found:

```
[...] Note there are NO brackets in this line. Putting the square brackets around
something means "get the contents of", so you were effectively defeating the
LEA op. [...]
```

I want to pass both arguments at `EBP+16` and `EBP+20` by reference, but how can I do that if can't use brackets? If I don't put them, then the compiler throws an error (`C2424`).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
MOV ECX, EBP+16
MOV EDX, EBP+20
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I said that the compiler throws an error while doing that.

Comment: @cdonts You can just `MOV ECX, EBP` then `ADD ECX, 16`.

Comment: That's reasonable but it doesn't work with `LEA`. The compiler throws `C2415: improper operand type` Any ideas?

Comment: Is your goal to explicitly use `LEA`?

Comment: Should I use `LEA` if I need to pass arguments by reference?

Comment: No, you can simply use `MOV` to move addresses (references) around.

Answer (score 1):

`lea` has one type of operation, so use the syntax that makes your compiler glad (for example, `fasm` requires brackets always, while `masm` requires its absence around label arguments).

Note, that:

- Windows calling conventions require you to preserve  `ebx` during calls;
- I doubt taking addresses of 3rd and 4th arguments was really your intention;
- You can use `push dword [ebp+xxx]` instruction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using the `__asm` statement from the VC++ compiler. I want to pass the 3rd and 4th arguments by reference, why you doubt?

Comment: @cdonts Aren't they already references in your outer function?

Comment: I think so, but using `MOV` works only for the 1st and 2nd arguments (they are passed by values). The last two values which I want to pass by reference doesn't work.

Comment: If your outer function takes 3rd and 4th arguments by reference, you have to use `mov ecx, [ebp+16]`, `mov edx, [ebp+20]`.

Comment: My function is beeing called like this: `ASMFunction(a, b, &c, &d)`. If I use `MOV` then the last two arguments will be passed by value to the new function, or not?

Comment: Well, `[ebp+8]` now contains the value of `a`, `[ebp+16]` the address of `c`. And that's what you want to forward to `Function`. So you just have to use `mov` for all parameters.

Comment: Mean, you gonna ignore all I said (to use `mov` and to preserve `ebx`)?

Comment: I will use `mov` like you said instead of `lea`. I really don't understand what you mean when you say "preserve `ebx`". Can you please  explain me that in plain English? I'm very new to ASM.

Comment: It means that after return from function `ebx` should have the same value it had before the call. Either do not use it, or `push ebx` at the start of a function and `pop ebx` before return.

Comment: Ok I'll not use it. Can I use `ESI` instead?

Comment: No -) The callee has to preserve its caller's `ebx`, `ebp`, `esi`, `edi`.

Comment: So what should I use instead of `ebx`?